# Looping through assets in Vue.js static directory

Tags: webpack, vue.js, get

I've created a simple app in Vue (using the Webpack template) that has a carousel in it. What I would like to do is loop through all of the images in `static/images` to create that carousel. I know this is probably a dumb question, but how would I go about doing this? Do I need to perform a `GET` request?

The reason I'm asking is because I'm going to hand this off to a client to be hosted on their server. They would like to be able to add additional images to the carousel themselves if needed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

From this [webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-with-expression) you can get all files in the directory or specific files based on a regex search pattern.

You could do something like:

```
var cache = {};

function importAll (r) {
  r.keys().forEach(key => cache[key] = r(key));
}

importAll(require.context('../components/', true, /\.js$/));
```

If you a need an array of image names from the server you could do this:

```
<template lang="html">
   <div style="height: 100px">
     <div :key="key" v-for="(img, key) in images" >
       <img :src="imageDir + key.substr(1)" class="" >
     </div>
    </div>
 </template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      imageDir: "/your/path/to/images/", // you know this already just from directory structure
      images: {}
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.importAll(require.context(this.imageDir, true, /\.png$/))
  },
  methods: {
    importAll(r) {
      var imgs = {}
      r.keys().forEach(key => (imgs[key] = r(key)))
      this.images = imgs
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I am not entirely sure if I am doing it correctly but it return the images from the directory and displays them as expected.

Comment: hmm I'm getting `TypeError: __webpack_require__(...).context is not a function`

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript can't directly access the contents of a file system. 
You'll have to pass the contents using a server-side script (PHP,NodeJs…).
However, if you would go thought this you need that images named are sequential, then you can loop through names and check if image exist or not.

I think it would be better if you have a service-side when your client can upload images, create an API to list all images, then you performer a get request.

Comment: That's true in the general case, but when you're using Webpack, it has access to the file system when it's creating the bundle - and that's what you can use to solve this problem.