# Dynamically get image paths in folder with Nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

[image]

I'm using nuxt with vuetify. I have a working carousel component .I want to generate a list of The .png files in the static folder. Following [Dynamically import images from a directory using webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42118296/dynamically-import-images-from-a-directory-using-webpack) and Following https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#context-module-api my component looks like:

```
 <template>
  <v-carousel>
    <v-carousel-item v-for="(item,i) in items" :key="i" :src="item.src"></v-carousel-item>
  </v-carousel>
</template>


<script>

  var cache = {};
  function importAll(r) {
    r.keys().forEach(key => cache[key] = r(key));
  }
  var getImagePaths = importAll(require.context('../static/', false, /\.png$/));
  // At build-time cache will be populated with all required modules. 
  export default {
    data: function() {
      return {
        items: getImagePaths
      };
    }
  };
  //     export default {
  //       data() {
  //         return {
  //           items: [{
  //               src: "/52lv.PNG"
  //             },
  //             {
  //               src: "https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/carousel/sky.jpg"
  //             },
  //             {
  //               src: "https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/carousel/bird.jpg"
  //             },
  //             {
  //               src: "https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/carousel/planet.jpg"
  //             }
  //           ]
  //         };
  //       }
  //     };
  //
</script>
```

I want to search through the static folder and grab the paths to the images , put them in an array and export them to the html template.

I've found that if I edit the script's items array to look the following it will work:

items: [
            {
                src: '/52iv.png'
            },
            {
                src: '/91Iv.png'
            },
             ....

How can I adjust my code to get the result I need?

EDIT:

I looked at the proposed solution , but after copying it verbatum I got the following error.

[image]

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48236354/looping-through-assets-in-vue-js-static-directory) help?

Comment: Thank you I tried it verbatim but got the following error - Please see edit

Comment: are you sure your path is correct? what happens if you do `'../main/'` or `'~/main/` instead? in regards to your original code. it looks like your carousel component is only one folder deep.

Comment: @ryeMoss , I've changed the folder to static

Comment: I believe I was able to get it working using require.context() and the files in /main/. I imagine it would work the same in /static/. Unfortunately I'm also not very familiar with webpack to help out with your new method

Comment: Unable to comment, so adding it here. Can you try excluding node_modules from Babel transpilation? A similar '_webpack_' issue was bypassed through this simple hack.

Comment: I'm brand new to node, webpack etc. (Mostly use python ) Would you mind explaining how to do this?

Comment: @user61629 pls follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37823764/how-include-and-exclude-works-in-webpack-loader), the discussion in the comments sums up the understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following appears to work:

```
<template>
  <v-carousel>
    <v-carousel-item v-for="(item,i) in items" :key="i" :src="item.src"></v-carousel-item>
  </v-carousel>
</template>


<script>
  var cache = {};
  const images = require.context('../static/', false, /\.png$/);
  var imagesArray = Array.from(images.keys());
  var constructed = [];
  function constructItems(fileNames, constructed) {
    fileNames.forEach(fileName => {
      constructed.push({
        'src': fileName.substr(1)
      })
    });
    return constructed;
  }
  var res = constructItems(imagesArray, constructed);
  console.log(res);
  export default {
    data: function() {
      return {
        items: res
      };
    }
  };
```