# How to get all the image files in a directory using vue.js / nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I am working on a nuxt.js project and getting error:

In browser I am seeing this error:

```
__webpack_require__(...).context is not a function
```

And, in terminal I am getting this error:

```
Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted
```

Here is my code

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'SectionOurClients',
  data() {
    return {
      imageDir: '../assets/images/clients/',
      images: {},
    };
  },

  mounted() {
    this.importAll(require.context(this.imageDir, true, /\.png$/));
  },

  methods: {
    importAll(r) {
      console.log(r)
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

I have used the above script from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48875151).

Please help, thanks.

---

**EDIT**: After following @MaxSinev's answer, here is how my working code looks:

```
<template lang="pug">
  .row
    .col(v-for="client in images")
      img(:src="client.pathLong")
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'SectionOurClients',
  data() {
    return {
      images: [],
    };
  },

  mounted() {
    this.importAll(require.context('../assets/images/clients/', true, /\.png$/));
  },

  methods: {
    importAll(r) {
      r.keys().forEach(key => (this.images.push({ pathLong: r(key), pathShort: key })));
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: why dont you use `import` instead of `require` ?

Comment: @Terry it's not quite correct answer. Both `import` and `require` imports file as module, if you want to import images you can do that only with specified webpack loader and there is no difference between `import` and `require` for webpack. But in question example we can not use `import` because we have to use webpack helper `require.context` to load all images dymically during bundling.

Comment: @Terry, even `.png`'s can be imported `import defaultAvatar from '@/assets/images/default-avatar.png'`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the webpack docs:

> The arguments passed to `require.context` must be literals!

So I think in your case  parsing of `require.context` failed.

Try to pass literal instead of `imageDir` variable

```
mounted() {
    this.importAll(require.context('../assets/images/clients/', true, /\.png$/));
},
```

It is necessary because webpack can not resolve your runtime variable value during bundling.

Comment: thanks for your help, I have included working code in my answer.

Comment: when i am adding .pdf its throwing error. is there any way to get list of all files from a folder?

Comment: @SudhirKGupta if you want to involve pdf file to the bundling process you should add, for example, `file-loader` definition for your file type after that it will be resolved by webpack.

Answer (score 7):

Solution for vue 3 with vite:

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
const fonts = import.meta.glob('@/assets/fonts/*.otf')
console.log(fonts)
</script>
```

Read more: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/77